# datepicker UI When out of focus not collapsing

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, datetimepicker

[image]

datetimepicker when focus is out by mouse click
       Hi all, When i click mouse pointer out of the bootstrap datetime picker div i get the trails without css as seen in the attached image. And time picker also not to be seen

Comment: can u please make it as fiddle  ?

Comment: unfortunately its confidential part of my project. Any hints to overcome will be cool.

Comment: then how do you expect us to help you, if you don'y provide any code?

Comment: Simple thing datepicker was specified twice working now thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple thing datepicker was specified twice working now thanks :)